# ntfs-3g-mount: mount failed: Permission denied

Tags: mount, ntfs, ntfs-3g

When trying to mount a Bitlocker USB drive in Raspbian it throws this error:

```
ntfs-3g-mount: mount failed: Permission denied
```

This command works:

```
sudo mount -o ro,loop /mnt/tmp/dislocker-file /media/bitlocker
```

Which mounts the USB disk but also in read-only mode, however

```
sudo mount -o rw,loop /mnt/tmp/dislocker-file /media/bitlocker
```

Throws the Permission Denied error. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo mount -t ntfs /mnt/tmp/dislocker-file /media/bitlocker`

Comment: Permission denied